# How to serve index.html by default via bottle?

Tags: python, bottle

I have a route for static files defined as

```
@bottle.route('/status/<filename>')
def server_static(filename):
    root = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'status', 'public_html')
    return bottle.static_file(filename, root=root)
```

It works fine when I call `http://localhost/status/index.html` (or any other file).

**Is there a way to serve `index.html` by default when calling `http://localhost/status`?** This is equivalent to  [`DirectoryIndex`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) in Apache or [`index`](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/serving-static-content/) in nginx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `/status` rule and set the default value of `filename` to *index.html*:

```
@bottle.route('/status')
@bottle.route('/status/<filename>')
def server_static(filename='index.html'):
    root = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'status', 'public_html')
    return bottle.static_file(filename, root=root)
```

Comment: Note: I did not manage to have it working with `@bottle.route('/status')`, I had to append a slash:  `@bottle.route('/status/')`

Comment: @WoJ Bottle doesn't strip trailing slashes automatically, so /status and /status/ are different routes.